# Wicket Modal Window display on context menu option click

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I am new to wicket and developed a context menu with couple of options to run reports in HTML and Excel. Based on the menu item click i need to show a modal window to choose parameters required for that appropriate report.

I am handling the menu option choosing in below method of contextMenuBehavior java class

```
public void onRequest()
{
    final Component component = getComponent();
    final IRequestCycle cycle = component.getRequestCycle();
    final IRequestParameters parameters = cycle.getRequest().getRequestParameters();
    final String action = parameters.getParameterValue("action").toString(null);
    if (null == action)
    {
        cycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8",
                buildResponse()));
    } else
    {
        final String target = parameters.getParameterValue("targetId").toString(null);
        if (null == target)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    String.format("Did not receive a target object identifier for action [%s].", action));
        }
        menu.getAdapter().performActionOnTarget(component, action, target);
    }
}
```

*and in DomainActionHandler class -*

```
public void perform(final Component component, final String name, final Object target) throws ApplicationException
{
    if (target instanceof CannedReport)
    {
        final CannedReport report = (CannedReport) target;

        if ("runHtml".equals(name))
        {
            component.getPage().setResponsePage(new RunReport(report.getReportId()));
        } else if ("runExcel".equals(name))
        {
            //AjaxRequestTarget ajaxTarget = AjaxRequestTarget.get();
            component.getPage().setResponsePage(new ModalReport(ajaxTarget, report.getReportId(), ReportFormat.EXCEL));
        }
    }
}
```

*and in ModalReport class*

```
public ModalReport(AjaxRequestTarget target, String reportId, ReportFormat format)
{
    super();
    setDefaultModel(modelFactory.createReportsModel());
    reportFiltersWindow = addReportFiltersWindow(this, "reportFiltersWindow");

    final IModel<Boolean> acceptedModel = new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.FALSE);
    final IModel<ReportModel> filtersModel = modelFactory.createEditReportModel(reportId);
    reportFiltersWindow.setContent(new ReportFiltersPanel(reportFiltersWindow, filtersModel, acceptedModel));

    modals.showWindow(target, reportFiltersWindow, new WindowClosedHandler() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public void onWindowClosed(final AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            // some action
        }
    });
}
```

In order to show the modal window, i need AjaxRequestTarget at modals.showWindow in ModalReport java class. I am unable to figure out how to get that AjaxRequestTarget as it comes with a behavior. Please let me know how to get it. Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, when menu option is clicked, your `perform()` is called, and `AjaxRequestTarget.get()` returns `null`?

Comment: Yes @RomanPuchkovskiy. onRequest() method is invoked first thought whcih perform() is called.